# Google Maps hang my ubuntu

Tags: 13.04, firefox, google-chrome, google-maps

System hang after sometimes scrolling the map and zoom in-out. I tried different browser, chrome and firefox and the result was the same. I need to hardly shutdown my system and restart ubuntu to fix it.

Comment: This can have many reasons. Most probably it's a bug in your graphics driver (if I'm not mistaken, Google Maps uses WebGL), but it could also be CPU overheating, a broken memory module,.... You can try to disable WebGL in Firefox to find out if it's a graphics driver issue: Go to the address "about:config" and set webgl.disabled to true. If this "solves" the problem for you, you might want to switch to a different graphics driver and enable WebGL again. To find out if your RAM is OK, get the GRUB menu to show up on boot, launch memtest86 and let it run a few hours.

Comment: Are you using the FireBug add-on? I found myself that Google Maps was impossible to use when FireBug was enabled on that page (which made debugging my own site really difficult).

Comment: I'm having the same problem with google chrome only. Firefox seems to be working fine. I checked my ram and it is fine. Not only Google Maps freezes my Ubuntu box, but some youtube videos do too. A hard reset is the only way get my system back and running.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue and fixed it by creating a swap partition, a small detail that I completely forgot when doing my manual installation.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that:

1) swapoff -a

2) removing /swap.img from /etc/fstab

3) adding a swap partition to /etf/fstab:
partitionid     none    swap    sw  0   0

4) swapon -a

solve the problem!

This is a nasty bug! (IMO)